# Link titles are sometimes displayed in the text when a long text is pasted in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

I thought I'd be clever and embed a pithy saying in a link title, but the [title was displayed in the text of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/263906/1) rather than the alt text. After some experimentation, it seemed as if the problem is with the length of the title I was trying to use. That turns out not to be true. Manually adding and removing words didn't help me find the magic number. Here's the bug in action:

> [A pithy saying is worth its weight in gold.](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/marthag/text/humor/lwall.html "I've decided I don't want to be a manager.  Every time you try to be
>   responsive to your employees, they say you're being reactive and not
>   proactive.  And when you try to be proactive, they accuse you of
>   being capricious and arbitrary.  So I don't wanna be a manager...  ")

And here's a version of the same link that I *typed by hand* which works as expected:

> [A pithy saying is worth its weight in gold.](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/marthag/text/humor/lwall.html)

And another copy that's broken after I pasted it in from my clipboard:

> [A pithy saying is worth its weight in gold.](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/marthag/text/humor/lwall.html "I've decided I don't want to be a manager.  Every time you try to be
>   responsive to your employees, they say you're being reactive and not
>   proactive.  And when you try to be proactive, they accuse you of
>   being capricious and arbitrary.  So I don't wanna be a manager...  ")

In the grand scheme of things, the answer is to [stop](http://ask.metafilter.com/240287/It-hurts-when-I-do-this-so-stop-doing-it) posting long link titles.

Comment: It would have been funnier if you'd status-declined yourself :D

Answer (score 7):

Arg. I see what I did wrong. The text I copied in has carriage returns, which screw things up. When I typed the title text in by hand, I didn't press <kbd>enter</kbd> at the appropriate moments. So the title was valid.